# How to exclude Jenkinsfile and automation scripts in zip file pipeline utility plugin in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

my workspace structure in Jenkins is as show in below tree.

```
├───automation_scripts
├───dist
│   └───assets
│       ├───datasim
│       └───images
│           └───icons
├───node_modules
├───src
├───config_pm2.json
└───package.json
```

In the above directory while I was using zip pipeline utility plugin as shown in below command. How do I exclude automation_scripts directory(which contains my deployment scripts like Jenkinsfile etc)while creating zip file?
I was only able to use what folders need to include using glob: in below command.

```
zip dir: '', glob: '', zipFile: "node-app" + ".zip"
```

any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

The `zip` step's parameter `glob` only support **includes** pattern, **excludes** pattern not support.

And includes pattern follow [Ant style pattern](https://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html#patterns)

For you cause you should write as:

```
zip glob: 'dist/**, node_modules/**, src/**, *.json', zipFile: "node-app" + ".zip"
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Mar 19, 2021, Jenkins added the support to exclude files and directories to the `zip` command.

Example based on your use case:

```
zip zipFile: 'node-app.zip',
    dir: '',
    exclude: 'automation_scripts/'
```

Command options: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#zip-create-zip-file

Source code: https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-utility-steps-plugin/blob/e76d7fa068b57246e799b9ad181727604a2351ff/src/main/resources/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/utility/steps/zip/ZipStep/config.groovy