# Jenkins - "zip" Pipeline Utility - how to exclude Multiple files?

Tags: jenkins

I want to build "zip" file and exclude multiple files: Jenkinsfile and test1.txt
I am able to exclude one specific file. This works:

```
    stage ('First stage') {
        steps {
            zip zipFile: 'test.zip', archive: false, exclude: 'Jenkinsfile'
        }
```

But how I can add to exclude test1.txt file as well?
I tried:

`exclude: 'Jenkinsfile', 'test1.txt'`

`exclude: 'Jenkinsfile' 'test1.txt'`

But it doesn't work!!!

Suggested solution on this link [How to exclude Jenkinsfile and automation scripts in zip file pipeline utility plugin in Jenkins pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51924463/how-to-exclude-jenkinsfile-and-automation-scripts-in-zip-file-pipeline-utility-p) is NOT APPLICABLE!!!
Because `exclude` option is supported as explained on this link:
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#zip-create-zip-file

Thank you!!!

Comment: It DOES NOT!!!! They mentioned exclude is not supported while it is definetly supported! As you can see on this link
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#zip-create-zip-file

Comment: @IanW please remove your suggestion to close this issue! I edited the question and you can understand easily why this is not similar to what you have provided me! Thank you in advance!!!!!!!

Comment: THIS IS THE SOLUTION:
`exclude: 'Jenkinsfile, test1.txt'`

Comment: Wow, rather a visceral reaction! So, now you answered your own question (albeit in a comment), according to the official documentation; that's usually a good place to start. Perhaps you want to answer the other question and I'll vote your answer up.

Comment: As @VeljkoSbbb pointed out the correct solution is having your excluded files listed as comma separated but one string, your two attempts have comma or none and two separate strings. The Solution he points to is correct.